# How can I get the name of a function reference

Tags: perl

I am passing a function `func_foo` to a general-purpose handler `handle`:

```
sub func_foo {  # do something }

sub handle {
  my $func_ref = shift;
  # TODO: Print the name of func_ref.
  $func_ref->();
}

handle(\&func_foo);
```

How can I retrieve the name of the passed function (i.e., `func_foo`) at the `TODO` line inside `handle`?

For the example above, if I just do `print $func_ref`, I will get something like `CODE(0x21a8fca0)`.

Comment: You're probably looking for the functionality in the module `Sub::Identify`

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=413799

Comment: Thanks, ysth. I also find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419071/determining-the-subroutine-name-of-a-perl-code-reference